# Spring Integration and Transaction Management - how difficult need it be?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-integration

Using Spring Integration I am trying to built a simple message producing component. Basically something like this:

```
<jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter 
  channel="from.database"
  data-source="dataSource" 
  query="SELECT * FROM my_table"
  update="DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id IN (:id)"
  row-mapper="someRowMapper">
  <int:poller fixed-rate="5000">
      <int:transactional/>
  </int:poller>
</jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:splitter
  id="messageProducer"
  input-channel="from.database"
  output-channel="to.mq" />

<jms:outbound-channel-adapter
  channel="to.mq"
  destination="myMqQueue"
  connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
  extract-payload="true" />

<beans:bean id="myMqQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
  <!-- properties omitted --!>
</beans:bean>
```

The "messageProducer" may produce several messages per poll but not necessarily one per row.

My concern is that I want to make sure that rows are not deleted from my_table unless the messages produced has been committed to the MQ channel.

On the other hand I will accept that rows in case of db- or network failure are not deleted thus causing duplicate messages to be produced. In other words I will settle for a non-XA one-phase commit with possible duplicates.

When trying to figure out what I need to put to my Spring configuration I quickly get lost in endless discussions about transaction managers, AOP and transaction advice chains which I find difficult to understand - I know I ought to though.

But I fear that I will spend a lot of time cooking up a configuration that is not really necessary for my problem at hand.

So - my question is: Can it be that simple - or do I need to provide explicit configuration for transaction synchronization?

Comment: I know now that if the jms:outbound-channel-adapter was instead a jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter with a different datasource I could simply introduce a ChainedTransactionManager to manage the two datasources in the right order. But can I do something similar with a jdbc/jms mix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But can I do something similar with a jdbc/jms mix?

I'd say "Yes".

Please, read Dave Syer's article about [Best effort 1PC](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html), where the `ChainedTransactionManager` came from.

Comment: Thanks Artem - it is a very helpful article and I suppose it wont be much simpler than that:-) I am actually using the  org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager instead of the com.springsource.open.db.ChainedTransactionManager - but my inspiration came from this article. I will try to adapt the "best-jms-db" to a "best-db-jms" which is what I am in need of.

Comment: Glad to hear! If my answer is good, just accept to close the question.